# Conditions on freezing water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, phase-transition, kinetic-theory, navier-stokes, molecular-dynamics

Observing the freezing phenomenon of river, here are some questions pop up.

Comparing with pure water, impurity in water will alter melting point, what are the qualitative and quantitative explanation, I know specifically intermolecular interaction like salt and water will change molecular interaction.

Intuitively, stationary water will have higher melting point than running water as latter has higher velocity (Let's simplify the motion as 1D constant velocity). can anyone determine my guess and give an explicit formula between melting point and fluid velocity. Specifically, is there a critical temperature (other than absolute zero) that no matter how high the velocity of water is, it will freeze.

For a more complicated treatment, will the motion of water effects the melting point? Which means in 3D, acceleration/ constant velocity of linear translation and rotation of fluid, even more, the geometry of container.

Comment: On freezing point depression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression#Explanation

Comment: The motion of water has no effect on melting/freezing point. That's because the *relative* velocities of the molecules W.R.T. each other doesn't change, regardless of 'bulk' velocity.

Comment: Ice in lakes is the simpler version (though non-trivial), and ice in rivers is more complex (and involves "frazel ice", which is some excellent terminology). [Here's a good description of the processes from Britannica.](https://www.britannica.com/science/lake-ice/Ice-in-rivers)